Configuration kerberos authorization via JDBC for Cloudera Apach Hive
I'm running Apach Hive in a Docker container and using the following image:  https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hive
I want to add kerberos authorization to connect to Apach Hive via JDBC from a Java application.
Everything I could find:
hive-site.xml


<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
  <value>KERBEROS</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
  <value>hive/hive-server.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.keytab</name>
  <value>/home/mykeytab.keytab</value>
</property>


I generated a valid keytab file but the container start and after a while stoped.
There is only one configuration file in the container repository:
ivysettings.xml


<ivysettings>
  <!--name of the defaultResolver should always be 'downloadGrapes'. -->
  <settings defaultResolver="downloadGrapes"/>
  <!-- Only set maven.local.repository if not already set -->
  <property name="maven.local.repository" value="${user.home}/.m2/repository" override="false" />
  <property name="m2-pattern"
            value="file:${maven.local.repository}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
            override="false"/>
  <resolvers>
    <!-- more resolvers can be added here -->
    <chain name="downloadGrapes">
      <!-- This resolver uses ibiblio to find artifacts, compatible with maven2 repository -->
      <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
      <url name="local-maven2" m2compatible="true">
        <artifact pattern="${m2-pattern}"/>
      </url>
      <!-- File resolver to add jars from the local system. -->
      <filesystem name="test" checkmodified="true">
        <artifact pattern="/tmp/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).jar"/>
      </filesystem>

    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>



For what reason might this not work? It would be great to see an example of configuring kerberos for Cloudera Apach Hive
